# Log out in Kubuntu puts me to a black srceen

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown

I have installed Kubuntu 10.10. when i click leave-> logout the system turns into a black screen just like a dos screen rather than a graphical screen. Once there keyboard does not work. I have logged out but i have no idea how to login. I have to press the power button to turn the PC off and start again.

Why on earth is this happening ?

Comment: Please check if you can switch to a text console with CTRL-ALT-F1, if you can then it's a system hang, otherwise it might be a bug with Xorg/kdm .

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution after a lot of google srearch. CTRL-ALT-F1 puts me into a text console. So it can be system hang or bug with Xorg/kdm according to Joao Pinto(the person who commented on my question).

However there is a solution. In the file "/etc/kde4/kdm/kdmrc" if i uncomment the line "#Terminate-server = ture"
and restart the problem is gone. Very simple solution. Also an impossible one for a novice.

I have some question in my answer. Is this really a bug? Why that line is commented to create unreasonable suffering to the users ? very funny huh...

Comment: Shouldn't `ture` be `true`?

Comment: yes of course. it was a slip of keyboard. :P